# How to detect the main cause of app lagging issue?

Tags: android, background-service

I am an android developer and i created an android app which has a background service running.

I have basically created an app which shows chat heads whenever a notification arrives. user can tap on that chat head and reply to that message without opening native messaging app. (Just Like Facebook Messenger with chat heads).

My app runs very smooth in some devices like Vivo, Oppo. But it lags very much in some devices like Samsung and MI. I don't know what is going on here. My app has clean code and never crashes, it just lags and make the phone slower. on the other hand it runs very smooth in some deices.

I tried google but did not find any useful tips. I just want to know that if there is any way to detect the main cause of this lagging issue in some devices. App never crashes, never got any exceptions, don't have any error in code, but still it makes some deice slower and lags.

If anyone can help me finding the main cause of this lagging issue, then it would be a great help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use android studio profiler option to check whats causing lag in your app:
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler

ref tutorials:
https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/profiling-your-app-with-android-studio-7accc268cb98

Comment: Hi @Ashok_Kumar Thank you for replying. Actually I have never used 'android studio profiler option' as I don't have much experience developing android. Can you provide some more tutorial kind of stuff to get started with it?

Comment: Click the links... you'd be surprised!

Comment: For those who are looking for some good tips, Please go through this link, It has a great presentation on Android Performance Optimization. Link : http://blog.udinic.com/2015/09/15/speed-up-your-app